# Virtual hosting FTP problems with CakePHP v2.4.6

Tags: cakephp, ftp

I am having some trouble with my upload CakePHP 2.4.6 to GoDaddy. Specifically the file "CakeResponse.php" doesn't want to upload correctly. When I upload it GoDaddy appends a ".gdav" extension to it, and changes the permissions to "00".

I am using FileZilla 3.7.3 and have tried renaming it (both on server and locally), which works but does nothing. And it doesn't allow me to change permissions on the file.

```
Command:    SITE CHMOD 704 CakeResponse.php
Response:   550 Could not change perms on CakeResponse.php: Permission denied
```

Any thoughts on what the problem might be?

**Update:** I've downloaded Cake v2.4.0 and CakeResponse will still not upload. I've also tried from my Windows PC at work using FileZilla 3.7.4.1

Comment: I'm having this exact issue.  Specifically when I try and upload a file with set_time_limit(0); at the top, using NppFTP and FileZilla... Were you able to fix this without just resorting to using godaddy's file manager?  This is happening to every file I try to upload.  Using GoDaddy's file manager every time is a pain in the arse.

Comment: Yeah it was only the one file. I'm not sure what the time limit was, but since it was only the one file it has been okay. And hasn't happened with any of the other hundreds of files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not customer support for godaddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the issue by using the "File Manager" website that GoDaddy provides, which allowed me to upload the file with permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous comment, my guess is that gdav stands for GoDaddy antivirus...

I went ahead and called them and yes it is their new antivirus they are still working the bugs out on.

Answer (score 0):

In hopes of helping to lead to an answer with another case study, let me share the experience I had with the same issue, but on a WordPress file:

/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php

Here are my specs:

- GoDaddy Deluxe Web Hosting, Linux
- Cyberduck v 4.2.1
- Also tried in FileZilla v 3.6.0.2 (same results)
- MacBook, OS X v 10.6.8

To be clear, I also could not change permissions (although it deceptively acted like it was letting me) and renaming the file didn't help me either. I also tried uploading a new dummy file with a different name (work.php) and with different content (I think "WORK!" was all I wrote in it), which uploaded fine with normal permission (704 I think). I then tried pasting the contents of the above ajax-actions.php into it and re-uploading it. It added a .gdav to that file as well and changed the permissions to 000.

Using GoDaddy's File Manager became my workaround as well, thanks to timmsimpson (I may not have thought of that).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, issue with Go Daddy Anti-virus. login to GD host control panel, go to the File Manager, rename the file and remove the .gdav extension, select the file, change the file permissions to 644.

Update: I'm not sure if this is related to gdav, but for the past 3 weeks my WordPress sites, which normally load in 2 seconds are taking 5 seconds to never loading (connection resets, lost DB connections, etc) intermittently throughout the day every day for 3 weeks now. The other thing that was implemented 3 weeks ago on GD was SiteLock. Also this time of year is infrastructure rebuild/enhancement time at GD. POD6 is currently hosed.